# sql delete row when a column match

Tags: sql, sql-delete

i want to delete the wullfi row by match the authid

i must also say the aid is change so cant use that

[image: mysql]

Comment: you want to keep the `aid` reserved ?

Comment: "i must also say the aid is change so cant use that" - what does this mean?  What is wrong with, delete from your_table where aid = 6?

Comment: @AbdelraoufFerah no delete everything

Comment: @OldProgrammer im INSERT to this table from store so that id keep changing

Comment: Sorry you are going to have to provide a lot clearer details.  match authid how?  by what criteria?  Also tag the question with database type.

Comment: hmm 
on the store runs this code
``INSERT INTO `sb_admins` (`aid`, `user`, `authid`, `password`, `gid`, `email`, `validate`, `extraflags`, `immunity`, `srv_group`, `srv_flags`, `srv_password`, `lastvisit`) VALUES (NULL, '{username}', '{steamid}', '', '0', '', '', '0', '1', 'Vipz', NULL, NULL, '0')``


i want to remove that row when subscription  expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE authid = "STEAM_0:1:59560224";
```